# Select the better result match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a little problem for have the good solution. I need to search the better result.

I have 3 tables, rule, meaning, and rule_meaning. 1 rule can have 1 or more meaning.

This is the result for

```
SELECT * FROM rule, rule_meaning, meaning WHERE rule_meaning.rule_id = rule.id AND rule_meaning.meaning_id = meaning.i

rule.id rule.name   rule.id meaning_id  meaning.id  meaning.name
1   RADIO - Ecouter   1        1          1          ACTIVER
1   RADIO - Ecouter   1        6          6          RADIO
2   LUMIERE Allumer   2        1          1          ACTIVER
3   RADIO + volume    3        6          6          RADIO
4   RADIO - volume    4        6          6          RADIO
```

When i search ACTIVER and RADIO i want to have only RADIO - Ecouter (rule.id = 1)

I have tried

- WHERE meaning.name = ACTIVER AND meaning.name = RADIO but no result
- WHERE meaning.name = ACTIVER OR meaning.name = RADIO i have several result.

Comment: What errors do you get? What is the problem?... `meaning.name = ACTIVER AND meaning.name = RADIO` doesn't make any sense...how can anything have 2 values at the same time

Comment: Kindly share your schema and expected result in formatted text (not images)

Comment: In fact i want to select only result who match this 2 words ACTIVER and RADIO simultanely. That's why i said the result must be rule.id 1 it's the only

Answer (score 2):

You want to select rules that have both meanings ACTIVER and RADIO. You can do this with an aggregation:

```
select *
from rule
where id in
(
  select rule_id
  from rule_meaning 
  where meaning_id in (select id from meaning where name in ('ACTIVER', 'RADIO'))
  group by rule_id
  having count(*) = 2 -- both meanings
);
```

Another approach I like less would be to look up each value separately with `EXISTS` or `IN`. I am showing it here because it's the simple way how to approach the task.

```
select *
from rule
where id in
(
  select rule_id
  from rule_meaning 
  where meaning_id = (select id from meaning where name = 'ACTIVER')
)
and id in
(
  select rule_id
  from rule_meaning 
  where meaning_id = (select id from meaning where name = 'RADIO')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a case statement e.g

```
    CASE WHEN WHERE meaning.name = ACTIVER AND meaning.name = RADIO
    THEN ....
    ELSE
```

But i think what you're asking is

```
    WHERE meaning.name = ACTIVER AND rule.name = RADIO 
    AND rule.id = 1
```